# How to pass the 2nd selected row in datagridview to textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How do i pass my 2nd selected row in datagridview to textboxt. I only know how to put the first data. How do i pass the 2nd selected to textbox?

```
    Dim i As Integer

    i = DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Index

    Me.txtEmployeeID.Text = DataGridView2.Item(0, i).Value
```

Comment: Which line in your code is selecting the first? You'd need to make a change there to select the 2nd.

Comment: i = DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Index

This part ? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: nothing happen when i change the 0 to 1 .

Comment: You're assigning a value from the DaraGridView's Item collection into the TextBox. The assignment should be from the SelectedRows collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code it worked for me

```
Dim test As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString
```

You need to only change the `.cell(Here write the index value of the cell)`

Then you can use the string value to fill up textbox

Comment: She asking about 2nd selected row, not cell. So, it should be `DataGridView.SelectedRows(1).Cells(desiredIndex).Value.ToString`. Of course, there's need to put in, for example, `Try...Catch...End Try` block, or some other way, to check is there more than ome selected rows. Or, maybe, she need 2nd, next after selected row. Who know, question is little unclear.

Comment: If you are making an app just for test you can see its working with 0 even because there is the selected row if you want to work with fix row and column then just change the selectedrow to row only

For me its perfectly works

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
Dim secondRow as integer = 0

Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellClick
    'assuming that by second selected row, you mean the row after the selected row
    secondRow = e.RowIndex + 1
End Sub

Private Sub RowToTextBox()
    Try
        For i = 0 to DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
            txtEmployeeID.Text &= DataGridView2.Item(i, secondRow)
        Next
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox("You have selected the final row")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I don't think `Me.` is needed when referring to a textbox in the same form.

Comment: This won't give the 2nd selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many rows your user will select, I think looping thought the SelectedRows collection might work. I used the Name column because that is what I happened to have in my grid. Instead of a MessageBox you could add the values to a ListBox.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each GridRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        MessageBox.Show($"Value is {GridRow.Cells("Name").Value}")
    Next
End Sub
```